# Facebook embed page posts

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, embed

I have written a code for getting the post id's from a Facebook page trough the Graph API. And posts that shared or liked by the page comes up as an invalid post

```
function fbfeeds(data) {
  var entries = data.data || [];
  var html = ['<div class="fbfeed">'];
  for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
    var entry = entries[i];
    var pid = entry.id;
    var postid = pid.split("_");
    html.push('<div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=' + postid[1] + '&amp;id=' + postid[0] + '" data-width="750"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=' + postid[0] + '&amp;id=' + postid[0] + '">Innlegg</a> av <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/{page_name]/{page_id}">page_id</a>.</div></div>');
    html.push('<br>');
  }
  html.push('</div>');
  document.getElementById('fbfeed').innerHTML = html.join('');
}
```

[The page with the code](http://thekola19.weebly.com/feed.html)

How do I get the likes and shares to show up at posts?
Is there a universal code for embedding posts regardless of author?

Comment: so what's the question?